# Add a specific node version in ruby-alpine docker image

Tags: ruby, docker, alpine-linux

I'm using `ruby:2.6.5-alpine` as my base image and I'm trying to add a specific node version to it.

```
FROM ruby:2.6.5-alpine

RUN apk update \
 && apk upgrade --no-cache \
 && apk add  nodejs=12.18.0

# remaining configs
```

But when I specify a version, I'm getting this error

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  nodejs-12.15.0-r1:
    breaks: world[nodejs=12.18.0]
    satisfies: yarn-1.19.2-r0[nodejs]
```

if I simply do `RUN apk add nodejs` it works fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install nodejs from `main` repository while `v3.12` contain node `12.7.x`.

[alpine nodejs-12.18.x](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nodejs&branch=edge&repo=main)

```
FROM ruby:2.6.5-alpine

RUN apk update \
 && apk upgrade --no-cache
RUN apk add  --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/ nodejs=12.18.2-r0 npm
```